# Where does the JIRA Subversion plugin store the data and how can I extract it?

Tags: svn, jira

I am using the [Subversion JIRA Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/SVN/Subversion+JIRA+plugin) and need to query the file changes and commits for a given issue. Is it stored in an xml file or the JIRA database? Where can I start looking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’ve installed JIRA in “C:\program files”, then the mapping between JIRA issues and subversion commits is stored in:

C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Application Data\JIRA\caches\indexes\plugins\atlassian-subversion-revisions

Unfortunately, the files are not kept as Xml, so, it is not so that easy to use them.